# What is the Benefit of registering Zuul Proxy server to Eureka Server?

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am new to microservices and currently designing an application.
I have one eureka server for testing and one Zuul proxy server, I can connect to the services via Zuul even if it's registered or not registered to the Eureka server.

My zuul config is:

```
server:
  port: 8763

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul: TRACE

zuul:
  #prefix: /zuul-prefix
  routes:
    common-service:
      path: /common-service/**
      sensitiveHeaders: 
      serviceId: common-service #Eureka service ID.
    validation-service:
      path: /validation-service/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      serviceId:  validation-service #Eureka service ID.
    host:
      maxTotalConnections: 200
      maxPerRouteConnections: 20

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/,http://localhost:8762/eureka/
    fetchRegistry: true
```

So, what is the benefit of registering it to Eureka server?
Also, what is the impact of below property?:

```
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

Answer (score 0):

coming to fetch registry part

*Eureka clients fetches the registry information from the server and caches it locally. After that, the clients use that information to find other services. This information is updated periodically (every 30 seconds) by getting the delta updates between the last fetch cycle and the current one. The delta information is held longer (for about 3 mins) in the server, hence the delta fetches may return the same instances again. The Eureka client automatically handles the duplicate information.*

coming to first part about registering itself
it is not important but connecting to eureka server is, because since you are using serviceID in your routes(instead of url paths) requests are wrapped with hystrix command and load balanced with ribbon and it uses eureka to fetch service details configured in service IDs

i guess i m late to this thread, you might have already figured this part out :)